# What happens to the object I assign to $stdout in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

**EDIT: Don't bother reading this question, I just can't delete it. It's based on broken code and there's (almost) nothing to learn here.**

I am redirecting console output in my Ruby program and although it works perfectly there is one thing I'm curious about:

Here's my code

```
capture = StringIO.new
$stdout = capture
puts "Hello World"
```

It looks like even though I'm assigning my `capture` object to `$stdout`, `$stdout` contains a new and different object after the assignment, but at least the type is correct.

In other words:

```
$stdout.to_s              # => #<IO:0x2584b30>

capture = StringIO.new
$stdout = capture

$stdout.to_s              # => #<StringIO:0x4fda948>
capture.to_s              # => #<StringIO:0x4e3b220>
```

Subsequently `$stdout.string` contains `"Hello World"`, but `capture.string` is empty.

Is there something happening behind the scenes or am I missing something here?

**EDIT:** This might be specific to certain versions only. I'm using Ruby 2.0.0-p247 on Windows 8.1

Comment: Is that your actual code?

Comment: Sorry guys, Felix and falsetru were right, the value of `$stdout` is changed subsequentially. I didn't notice, because the 'Hello World' line was actually a placeholder for quite a lot of code, which I inherited from someone else and I didn't inspect it very thoroughly. -- Well, that was a waste of time, but thanks for helping me out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure there is no other manipulation of `$stdout` or `capture`happening in between?

For me, output looks different. Both `capture` and `$stdout` are the same object and subsequently answer to `string` with the same response (ruby 1.9.2):

```
require 'stringio'                                                                                                                             
$stdout.to_s              # => #<IO:0x2584b30>                                                                                                 

capture = StringIO.new                                                                                                                         
$stdout = capture                                                                                                                              

puts $stdout.to_s              # => #<StringIO:0x89a38c0>                                                                                      
puts capture.to_s              # => #<StringIO:0x89a38c0>                                                                                      
puts "redirected"

$stderr.puts $stdout.string # => '#<StringIO:0x89a38c0>\n#<StringIO:0x89a38c0>\nredirected'                                                                           
$stderr.puts capture.string # => '#<StringIO:0x89a38c0>\n#<StringIO:0x89a38c0>\nredirected'
```

Comment: I fear you might be right... Checking now.

Answer (score 2):

It works as expected.

```
>> capture = StringIO.new
=> #<StringIO:0x00000001ea8c00>
>> $stdout = capture
>> $stdout.to_s
>> capture.to_s
```

Above two line does not print anything because `$stdout` is now disconnected from terminal.

So I used `$stderr.puts` in following lines (can also use `STDOUT.puts` as Stefan commented):

```
>> $stderr.puts $stdout.to_s
#<StringIO:0x00000001ea8c00>
>> $stderr.puts capture.to_s
#<StringIO:0x00000001ea8c00>
```

`$stdout.to_s`, `capture.to_s` give me same result.

I used ruby 1.9.3. (Same for 2.0.0)

Comment: You can use `STDOUT.puts` instead.

Comment: @Stefan, Ah, you're right.

Comment: Of course I got the `to_s` values by other means :) As I said, there is no problem here, I'm just curious about what's happening.

Comment: @DanielRikowski, I just tested same code in Windows 7 (Ruby 2.0.0p247) and get same result.

Answer (score 1):

Although this question was the result of overlooking a change to the value of `$stdout`, Ruby does have the ability to override assignment to global vars in this way, at least in the C api, using [*hooked variables*](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_0_0_247/README.EXT#L536-549).

[`$stdout` actually does make use of this](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_0_0_247/io.c#L11778) to check whether the new value is appropriate (it checks [whether the new value responds to `write`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_0_0_247/io.c#L7053-7058)) and raises an exception if it doesn’t.

If you really wanted (you don’t) you could create an extension that defines a global variable that automatically stores a different object than the value assigned, perhaps by called `dup` on it and using that instead:

```c
#include "ruby.h"

VALUE foo;

static void foo_setter(VALUE val, ID id, VALUE *var){
  VALUE dup_val = rb_funcall(val, rb_intern("dup"), 0);
  *var = dup_val;
}

void Init_hooked() {
  rb_define_hooked_variable("$foo", &foo, 0, foo_setter);
}
```

You could then use it like:

```
2.0.0-p247 :001 > require './ext/hooked'
 => true 
2.0.0-p247 :002 > s = Object.new
 => #<Object:0x00000100b20560> 
2.0.0-p247 :003 > $foo = s
 => #<Object:0x00000100b20560> 
2.0.0-p247 :004 > s.to_s
 => "#<Object:0x00000100b20560>" 
2.0.0-p247 :005 > $foo.to_s
 => "#<Object:0x00000100b3bea0>" 
2.0.0-p247 :006 > s == $foo
 => false
```

Of course this is very similar to simply creating a setter method in a class that `dup`s the vale and stores that, which you can do in plain Ruby:

```ruby
def foo=(new_foo)
  @foo = new_foo.dup
end
```

Since using global variables is generally bad design, it seems reasonable that this isn’t possible in Ruby for globals.